# Dynamic Profile URL

Tags: api, stocktwits

Can the API provide a URL that retrieves a user's latest avatar.

Right now the initial OAuth call gives us the static URL for the avatar at that time. If the user changes their avatar later on, the API doesn't provide this.

E.g.

`http://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/avatar?username=bgajdero`

would return:

`http://static.stocktwits.com/avatars/ubu2gb3ug2i34.png`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Developer at StockTwits here. The best recourse presently would be to use the user stream endpoint and update the avatar from the user object there (i.e. https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/user/bgajdero.json). When you pull in stream messages it's also a good idea to update local representations of avatars from the user object in each message to stay updated as those are generally fresh.

We'll put this up for future review to see if there's any better options but for now this would be the best way to keep avatars updated.